# Custom Flip animation between fragments android support package

Tags: android

I am trying to find out how to create flip animation between 2 fragments.

I have tried the [CardFlip](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) training as a guide, but don't seem to be able to achieve it. 
I am using the android support package and set it to tween animation, but not successful.

How to implement flipping animations between fragment?

here is the first 2 xml i created from the guide, maybe you could see if am doing something wrong.
screen_flip_left_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <!-- Before rotating, immediately set the alpha to 0. -->
    <alpha
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:duration="0" />

    <!-- Rotate. -->
    <rotate
        android:valueFrom="-180"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full"/>

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 1. -->
    <alpha
        android:valueFrom="0.0"
        android:valueTo="1.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />
</set>
```

screen_flip_left_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <!-- Rotate. -->
    <rotate
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_full" />

    <!-- Half-way through the rotation (see startOffset), set the alpha to 0. -->
    <alpha
        android:valueFrom="1.0"
        android:valueTo="0.0"
        android:propertyName="alpha"
        android:startOffset="@integer/card_flip_time_half"
        android:duration="1" />

</set>
```

Comment: What is not working? is specific code crashing? More details please.

Comment: @QVDev first of all, i can't use the objectanimator from the guide because its not available in the android support package, so the code crashes there until i switch to tween animation. and then, i don't get any flip effect at all. i am not sure whether it is because i use a different interpolator element there; i use this     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" because i need to support down to api level 8 and the one in the guide is for api 11 upwards.

Comment: So when you change it to tween it works right? This is indeed probably because of api level. Maybe use tween for older api's and flip for newer api's? Or create a custom flip animation

Comment: @QVDev nope. i have not been able to get it to work. i must be doing something wrong in the xml. i would post it here so you see whether i am wrong. please do you have any setting or how to create a custom flip animation?..

Comment: @QVDev thanks for taking the time to help out. i have included the first 2 xml that i modified from the guide. probably you could see if am doing something wrong.

Comment: Same here!  Have you solved yet?

Comment: could anybody find a specific solution?

Answer (score 1):

android:propertyName is only for ObjectAnimator (Honeycomb+) animations, not view animations from Gingerbread.  A card flip animation is only possible using Honeycomb animator api's.  I created a fork of the support library to allow using Animator apis from [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com) for fragment transitions. Use the animator-transition branch of my [github project](http://www.github.com/kedzie/android_frameworks_support).   Once you have the modified support library look at http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html to make the animator xml.

Comment: Cant even import your project into eclipse. Trying to do it for several hours (bout 4hrs) in a row - no luck. Every time  something is wrong or missed in the project. Also your project want ActionBarSherlock which uses the support-v4 by itself. Could you please just provide a compiled jar of your version of supportv4 lib (like in v4/bin)?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml should contain values inside objectAnimator tag, not inside alpha and rotate tags. The objectAnimator has propertyName wherein you have already specified the property values.

Answer (score -1):

That not right! 
"Once you have the modified support library look at http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html to make the animator xml."

This doesn't really support v4 library.